# problems in looping JAGS model in R

Tags: r, loops, jags

I am trying to run 7 JAGS models in a loop with rjags, but am having trouble getting the loops to run.

First I create seven models, (model txt files are already created). The JAGS code seems to be fine and I think its my inexperience with R vectors that is the issue.

```
model1 <- NULL
model2 <- NULL
model3 <- NULL
model4 <- NULL
model5 <- NULL
model6 <- NULL
model7 <- NULL

for (i in 1:totaltime) { #where totaltime is length=7
assign(paste("model",i,sep=""), jags.model(paste("model",i,".txt",sep=""),        data=DataList , #inits=initsList , 
                      n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps ))
}
```

This part runs fine and creates the seven models, then the burn-in step:

```
for (i in 1:totaltime) {
update(paste("model",i,sep=""), n.iter=burnInSteps)
}
```

This part gets the error: Error in object[[name, exact = TRUE]] : subscript out of bounds. However if I just type:

```
update(model1, n.iter=burnInSteps)
```

That works fine. Why doesnt the update function recognize the loop paste? Also the next line says:

```
for (i in 1:totaltime) {
paste("codaSamples",i,sep="")=coda.samples(paste("model",i,sep=""),      variable.names=parameters,n.iter=nPerChain,thin=thinSteps)
}
```

Which gives the error message: Error in model$iter : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

However if I run the vector as:

```
 codaSamples1=coda.samples(model1, variable.names=parameters,n.iter=nPerChain,thin=thinSteps)
```

It works fine, so frustrating!

Comment: Avoid `assign`: it leads to that kind of bug (`paste("model",i,sep="")` is a string with the name of a variable, not the variable itself), and much worse. You can store the results in a list: `models[[i]] <- jags.model(...)`, `codaSamples[[i]] <- ...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you specifying things as lists seems to have solved this.